# Are there serious performance differences between using pickleType and relationships?

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say there is a table of People. and let's say that are 1000+ in the system. Each People item has the following fields: name, email, occupation, etc.

And we want to allow a People item to have a list of names (nicknames & such) where no other data is associated with the name - a name is just a string.

Is this exactly what the pickleType is for? what kind of performance benefits are there between using pickle type and creating a Name table to have the name field of People be a one-to-many kind of relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is one good use case of sqlalchemy's `PickleType` field, [documented very well here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType). There are obvious performance advantages to using this.

Using your example, assume you have a `People` item which uses a one to many database look. This requires the database to perform a `JOIN` to collect the sub-elements; in this case, the `Person's` nicknames, if any. However, you have the benefit of having native objects ready to use in your python code, without the cost of deserializing pickles.

In comparison, the list of strings can be pickled and stored as a `PickleType` in the database, which are internally stores as a `LargeBinary`. Querying for a `Person` will only require the database to hit a single table, with no `JOIN`s which will result in an extremely fast return of data. However, you now incur the "cost" of de-pickling each item back into a python object, which can be significant if you're not storing native datatypes; e.g. string, int, list, dict.

Additionally, by storing pickles in the database, you also lose the ability for the underlying database to filter results given a WHERE condition; especially with integers and datetime objects. A native database call can return values within a given numeric or date range, but will have no concept of what the string representing these items really is.

Lastly, a simple change to a single pickle could allow arbitrary code execution within your application. It's unlikely, but must be stated.

IMHO, storing pickles is a nice way to store certain types of data, but will vary greatly on the type of data. I can tell you we use it pretty extensively in our schema, even on several tables with over half a billions records quite nicely.